# CUDA core pipeline

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, pipeline

I am following [this article](http://cstar.iiit.ac.in/~kkishore/GPUModel.pdf) about a prediction model for GPU. In page 5 second column almost at the end they state

> One has to finally take care of the fact that each of the Nc cores(SPs) in an SM on the GPU has a D-deep pipeline that has the effect of executing D threads in parallel.

My question is related to the **D-deep pipeline**. What does this pipeline look like? Is it something similar to the pipeline of the CPU (I mean **only** the idea because GPU-CPU are architectures completely different) about the fetch, decode, execute, write-back?

Is there a doc where this is documented?

Comment: And about "D" - the "D" seems to be 2 in early Fermi SM (if we take core clock as our base) - http://moodle.technion.ac.il/pluginfile.php/375213/mod_resource/content/1/Lecture%2313-FromFermitoKepler.pdf "GF100 SM Warp is 32 threads – two cycles to complete a Warp - NVIDIA solution - *ALU clock is double the Core clock*" (double ALU clock looks like there are two times more ALU available to warps). And in Kepler's SMX D=1: "GK104 SMX - *No more “dual clocked ALU”*". Also check image http://www.realworldtech.com/includes/images/articles/g100-6.gif from http://www.realworldtech.com/gt200/9/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, GPU SM's pipeline looks bit like CPU's. The difference is in frontend/backend proportions of the pipeline: GPU has single fetch/decode and a lot of small ALU (think as there are 32 parallel Execute subpipelines), grouped as "Cuda cores" inside the SM. This is similar to superscalar CPUs (e.g. Core-i7 has 6-8 issue ports, one port per independent ALU pipeline).

There is GTX 460 SM  (image from [destructoid.com](http://www.destructoid.com/while-amd-goes-for-brains-nvidia-goes-for-brawn-210726.phtml); we can even see what is inside each CUDA core two pipelines: Dispatch port, then Operand collector, then two parallel Units, one for  Int and other for FP and the Result queue): [image: GTX 460 SM]

(or better quality image  http://www.legitreviews.com/images/reviews/1193/sm.jpg from http://www.legitreviews.com/article/1193/2/)

We see that there is one Instruction cache in this SM, two warp schedulers and 4 dispatch units. And there is single register file. So, first stages of GPU SM pipeline are common resource of SM. After instruction planning they are dispatched to CUDA cores, and each core may have its own multistaged (pipelined) ALU, especially for complex operations.

Length of the pipeline is hidden inside the architecture, but I assume that total pipeline depth is much more than 4. (There is clearly instructions with 4 clock ticks latency so ALU pipeline is >= 4 stages and total SM pipeline depth is assumed to be more than 20 stages: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/390366/instruction-latency/ )

There is some additional info about instruction full latencies: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/419456/how-to-schedule-warps-/ - 24-28 clocks for SP and 48-52 clocks for DP.

Anandtech posted some pictures of AMD GPU, and we can assume that main ideas of pipelining should be similar for both vendors: http://www.anandtech.com/show/4455/amds-graphics-core-next-preview-amd-architects-for-compute/4

[image: AMD core according to Anandtech]

So, fetch, decode, and Branch units are common for all SIMD cores, and there are lot of ALU pipelines. In AMD the register file is segmented between groups of ALU, and in Nvidia it was shown as single unit (but it may be implemented as segmented and accessed via interconnect netwoork)

As said in [this work](http://web.archive.org/web/20111007211333/http://www.moderngpu.com/intro/performance.html)

> Fine-grained parallelism, however, is what sets GPUs apart. Recall that threads execute synchronously in bundles known as warps. GPUs run most efficiently when the number of warps-in-flight is large. Although only one warp can be serviced per cycle (Fermi technically services two half-warps per shader cycle), the SM's scheduler will immediately switch to another active warp when a hazard is encountered. If the instruction stream generated by the CUDA compiler expresses an ILP of 3.0 (that is, an average of three instructions can be executed before a hazard), and the **instruction pipeline depth is 22 stages**, as few as eight active warps (22 / 3) may be sufficient to completely hide instruction latency and achieve max arithmetic throughput. GPU latency hiding delivers good utilization of the GPU's vast execution resources with little burden on the programmer.

So, only one warp at a time will be dispatched every clock from pipeline frontend (SM scheduler) and there is some latency between scheduler's dispatch and time when ALU finish calculations.

There is part of picture from Realworldtech http://www.realworldtech.com/cayman/5/ and http://www.realworldtech.com/cayman/11/ with Fermi pipeline. Note the `[16]` note in every ALU/FPU - this means that there are 16 same ALU physically.

[image: fermi pipeline according to Realwordtech]

Comment: there are also some notes here http://www.ece.lsu.edu/gp/notes/set-nv-org.pdf with simple pipeline flow charts

Comment: and nvidia shows parts of pipeline here: http://www.geforce.com/Active/en_US/en_US/pdf/GeForce-GTX-680-Whitepaper-FINAL.pdf (page "10" - scheduling part of pipeline = frontend)

Comment: There are slides from Texas: http://sc.tamu.edu/systems/eos/GPU-Intro.pdf with "Simplified multi-SIMD GPU Pipeline" (slide 11) and comparison with classic and superscalar CPUs: slides 7-10. Check also "CUDA Core (CC) Architecture" slide

Comment: This was indeed very useful I just took a look at the references and there's plenty of info. Thank you.

Comment: @BRabbit27, And I think the last one: sc.tamu.edu/systems/eos/GPU-Intro.pdf  may be the best. You are welcome to ask any thing more here in comments.

Comment: @osgx I would appreciate if you drop in the comments relevant documents for nvidia titan (on the same issue you have discussed here). Thanks

Comment: Titan is based on Kepler (SMX): http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/kepler/NVIDIA-kepler-GK110-Architecture-Whitepaper.pdf, Ujaldon (fellow) from GPGPU2 2014 http://gpu.cs.uct.ac.za/Slides/Kepler2.pdf (with Roofline!) and BSN http://www.brightsideofnews.com/2012/03/22/nvidia-kepler-analysis-another-masterpiece-from-the-architects-of-g80-or/

Answer (score 2):

Ordinary thread-level parallelism comes about in a GPU SM when multiple warps are available for execution.  Hardware multithreading is described [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#hardware-implementation)

The paper is fairly old and has the GTX 280 GPU in view.  GPUs prior to the Fermi generation had a SM processing arrangement that looks a little different than the SM arrangement in Fermi and later GPUs.  The high-level processing effect is the same -- 32 threads in a warp are executed in "lockstep" -- but whereas later SMs have at least 32 SP's (cores) per SM, GPUs prior to the Fermi generation had fewer cores per SM -- typically 8.  The effect is that a given warp instruction is executed in stepwise fashion, and each "core" or "SP" is in effect handling multiple lanes within the warp (in a stepwise fashion) in order to process a particular warp instruction.  I believe (based on what I see in the paper) that this is the "pipeline" that is being referred to.  In effect, each "core" in a GTX 280 has a "4-deep pipeline" that is handling 4 threads (out of the warp) and therefore requires 4 clocks (minimum) to actually complete processing of the 4 threads in the warp that are assigned to it.  This is documented [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capability-1-x)  and you may wish to compare the description to that given for later GPU generations such as the cc 2.0 description given [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capability-2-x).

And yes, for those who would argue with my usage of "cores" and "SP's", I agree that it's an inadequate description of how the compute resources in a GPU SM are actually laid out, but I believe this description is consistent with NVIDIA marketing and training literature, and consistent with the way the term "core" or "SP" is being used in the referenced paper.

Comment: Are you sure? I just checked it and seems perfectly fine. Anyways, I think what you say about thread-level parallelism is already covered and then there is this D-deep pipeline, I'm not sure about this though. That's why I put the reference to avoid confusions, it should be working the link. Thanks

Comment: I was able to download the paper.  I have edited my answer with a different "theory" as to their usage of "pipeline".

Comment: Why do you say it's an inadequate description, cores and SPs? I'm curious now, I mean I think Nvidia uses them interchangeably.

Comment: Because there aren't actually any computing cores.  There are a variety of execution units, that do different things.  For example, there is a SP unit, a DP unit, an integer unit, etc.  They are not all unified into the same "core" and the resource ratios (number of a particular type of execution unit per SM) vary. This is an aside, not really relevant to this discussion.  I'm just trying to deflect future arguments that aren't central to the discussion.